# Will an official 4G internal modem card from a ThinkPad W540 fit in a W520?

Tags: laptop, thinkpad, cellular-internet, aircard

My ThinkPad W520 has an add-in slot to support a cellular modem. Officially, this slot's supported module is the [GOBI 2000](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-w-series-laptops/thinkpad-w520/4282/accessories/pd009784), a 3G modem with multi-carrier support.

I am aware of an upgraded version of this same module, the [ThinkPad EM7345](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/accessories/pd031021-thinkpad-em7345-4g-lte-mobile-broadband-overview-and-service-parts), which is a 4G-capable modem.

Per the documentation, this card is an add-on option for the ThinkPad W540; the next model up from the ThinkPad W520 I own.

I am curious if this card will work on my machine anyway.

So is there any technical reason the "official" 4G modem linked above would not function in the W520, be it a hardware whitelist, incompatible connectors, or any other reason?

Two notes:

- Whether or not this is a "supported" configuration is no longer relevant - W520s are 2011-era machines with warranties that all expired no later than 2016.
- I am asking for experience here, not official documentation. For example, per documentation, the ThinkPad W520 only supports 16GB of RAM max and can't be upgraded beyond Windows 8, but in reality, it will quite happily support 32GB and run Windows 10 with full functionality. ThinkPads can be pushed beyond their OEM specs.

Comment: These 4G internal cards are not linked to a specific machine type (they work in multiple machine types).  If it fits properly and has drivers, it should work. I use external cards not internal but they work in multiple machines.

Comment: @John Good info in general, but It isn't beyond certain PC manufacturers to have BIOS-level whitelisting so that only certain brands or even specific modules will work. I just want to confirm that there are no such shenanigans in the W520 before shelling out the money to buy the card (the 4G one is rather expensive)

Comment: The same 4G cards work in multiple machine models, and I don't think they are whitelisted in BIOS. I am not entirely certain but I do not think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sadly, it won’t work.

#### They are not physically compatible.

The ThinkPad EM7345 4G LTE uses a [PCI Express M.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2) connector and the Qualcomm Gobi 2000 uses a [Mini-PCI Express (mPCIe)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_Mini_Card) connector. 100% different phsyical connectors.

Here is the ThinkPad EM7345 as pictured from an eBay listing. Note the position of the notch and the amount of connectors on that right-most connector.

[image: ThinkPad EM7345 pic from an eBay listing.]

And now look at the Qualcomm Gobi 2000 as pictured in another eBay listing; note the notch is closer to the left and the pin count is different.

[image: Qualcomm Gobi 2000 pic from an eBay listing.]

Comment: Aaaaaah you beat me to it.. I was just researching the physical card layouts and was next going to ask if the connector difference was a deal-breaker, and sure enough, it is. Good find, and thank you.